# HTML file input - Multiple and at least one of certain type

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload

Weird question: I want to accept multiple files of (generally) any type to my input, but at least one needs to be of a certain format. Is there an HTML tag for this, or do I need to write some other code to check all files selected?

To clarify: I need at least one PDF in the list. Thus, PDF, docx, docx is legal; PDF, PDF, docx, jar, zzz is legal; docx, docx is not.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are exactly trying to do. But this [link](http://prasadhonrao.com/javascript-series-part-2-accept-user-input-using-html-form/) might be of a good use.

If you're trying to do something really general, like accept anything, javascript might be a good way to distinguish between what is allowed and what not.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this with a few lines of Javascript. I upload to a queue provided by an Angular Module (https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload) and then scan the queue and make sure at least one is of the correct type.